# wordpress plugin publishes text as HTML but will not let me add line breaks

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins, customization

On a plugin I use it asks for the title of the section to be shown to users of my site. The problem is that the input does not accept HTML and just posts it as text on my page.

My problem is that I want line breaks in the title being shown to my users but it will only output it as one continuous line of text till it reaches the end of its allotted space and only then does it go to the next line. The HTML it outputs is just an `<h2>` heading.

My question is, where do I look to find the input value I saved in order to insert the code to give line breaks where I want them on the output since the input field ignores and removes them upon saving.

You can see what I mean on this page (http://devilpods.com/product/carolina-reaper-world-record-hot-pepper-seeds-in-pod/). Directly below the videos you will see the text: "Share, Tweet, Email A Friend... With Buttons Below For Instant 10% Off!!!".

I had to input that text in the plugins admin panel for it to show there, but nothing I do will give me line breaks where I want them in the sentences. Where is that input data stored and how do I manipulate it? No matter what I put in the input it comes out as plain text.

Comment: do you want the html content in questen & answer Tab in you site?

Comment: use textarea field to achieve this.